# The Namespace X already contains a definition for XX?

Tags: c#, .net, http, interface, request

I don't understand this error I am getting. I have tried to clean and build my project several times. Can anyone help me?
Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HTTPrequestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lstWebSites = new List<string>
            {
                "www.mearstransportation.com",
                "www.amazon.com",
                "www.ebay.com",
                "www.att.com",
                "www.verizon.com",
                "www.sprint.com",
                "www.centurylink.com",
                "www.yahoo.com"
            };
            string filename = @"RequestLog.txt";
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                {
                    foreach (string website in lstWebSites)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        {
                            MyWebRequest request = new MyWebRequest();
                            request.Request(website);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyWebRequest.cs - the problem is here: public class MyWebRequest
Error is: "The namespace HttpRequestApp already contains a definition for MyWebRequest"

```
using HTTPrequestApp.MyWebRequest;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HTTPrequestApp
{
    public class MyWebRequest : IWebRequest
    {
        public void Request(string strWebSite)
        {
            List<string> lstWebSites = Program.GetList(strWebSite);
            using (var client2 = new TcpClient(strWebSite, 80))
            {
                using (NetworkStream stream = client2.GetStream())
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                using (StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    //writer.AutoFlush = true;
                    writer.WriteLine("GET / HTTP/1.1");
                    writer.WriteLine("HOST: {0}:80", lstWebSites[1]);
                    writer.WriteLine("Connection: Close");
                    writer.WriteLine();
                    writer.WriteLine();

                    string theresponse = reader2.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(theresponse);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IWebRequest.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using MyWebRequest.Lib;

namespace HTTPrequestApp.MyWebRequest
{
    public interface IWebRequest
    {
        Task<List<strWebSite>> GetList();
        void Request();
    }
}
```

To give an over view of what I am trying to accomplish here is: Send HTTP request to get the initial page. Get back the HTTP response and check that it is a 200 response code. And time how long it took to retrieve the response. 
This is a console app but I need to not have it depend on the console, it needs to be an independent application so I can use it somewhere else. 
If anyone has any suggestions on how I can simplify my code please let me know. 
thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You have a `HTTPrequestApp.MyWebRequest` namespace and a `HTTPrequestApp.MyWebRequest` class name: c# compiler get confused (and human too...)

Consider renaming the namespace in something such `HTTPrequestApp.MyWebRequestNameSpace` if you really want a different namespace.

Comment: The error is 'HTTPrequestApp.MyWebRequest' does not implement interface member 'HTTPrequestApp.IWebRequest.Request();

Comment: Interface declare a method Request without parameters, MyWebRequest has a method Request with a string parameter, but no method with the interface signature.
Add a method `public virtual void Request()` in MyWebRequest class (or change the declaration in `IWebRequest` interface)

Comment: And of course, you have to implement also `Task<List<strWebSite>> GetList()` in your MyWebRequest class

Comment: I would rather change the declaration in IWebRequest, how would I do that?

Comment: `void Request(string strWebSite);` instead of `void Request();` in interface declaration

Comment: What using reference will I need to be able to use strWebsite? I tried Collections.Generic, NetworkInformation because it is a list of websites, I tried System.Net; noting works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93518/discussion-between-newdev-and-gian-paolo).